# which is best way to add books list in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am building the simple program where i have pre filled books with name , author , price in the Jtable so that i can show them in list.

Initially i created 2d array and it worked ok.

But now i want my program to dynamically add or delete in that list.

but array can't do that so which is best way to do that. with example will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would suggest that you define your own implementation of the [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface (probably by subclassing [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)).  Then, as Andrezj suggests, you can use an ArrayList internally to hold the data.  See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) on using the `JTable`.  It's more work, but it gives you more control over the data.

If you don't want to do that, then you can use the [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), which allows you to [add rows dynamically](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.util.Vector%29), but it's not type safe, and not threadsafe if you use `Vector`s to provide the data.  In fact, I'm not sure exactly what happens when you supply a row in the form of a `Vector` and then change that `Vector` after it's been added to the table.  If the `DefaultTableModel` makes it own (deep?) copy then it might be a non-issue, but I don't know if it does that.  Perhaps someone knowledgable can comment

Comment: Is there any example which shows how i can implement abstractTablemodel with arrayList. i am new to java so don't know how to do

Comment: sorry buddy but i am getting confused. Actuially i have a separate class named Book whose properties are name , author,price. how can i link that class with Jtable model. in that example there are widgets which i don't kno\w yet

Comment: Widget is just the example class the article is using.  Just replace it with your Book class wherever you see it :)  The 2nd page of the article has all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You may use generic [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).
If your book information has constant size, you can create an `ArrayList` of arrays. Here is an example with simple `String` array, change it to  `JTable` if this is the container you use.

```
private ArrayList<String[]> books = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

You will not have to worry about initializing the array list with initial size, like arrays.

```
String[] bookInfo1  = new String[3];
   bookInfo1[0] = "Adam Smith";  
   bookInfo1[1] = "Some Title";
   bookInfo1[2] = "1981";   
 books.add(bookInfo1);
```

Comment: how can i add the in Jable like JTable jt = new JTable( books, tableFields );-------it gives error

Comment: You can't add an ArrayList to a JTable unless you create a custom model. That is why the DefaultTableModel has been suggested since it does support a Vector which is basically the same thing as an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

> in the Jtable

Use the DefaultTableModel. You can dynamically add rows using the addRow(...) method.

Or if you are creating "Book" ojects to show in your JTable you can use the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/).